# GET current month plus last 13 month SQL

Tags: sql

I would like to modify the query which will also include the data from this month.

```
SELECT TOP (14) Entity = 'Total_Group'
    , Scenario = 'Actual'
    , Date = TRIM(CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id) * -1, GETDATE())) as CHAR(4))
    + ' P'
    + CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id) * -1, GETDATE())) as VARCHAR(2)))
FROM [sys].[all_objects]
```

the result of this table

starts with `2022P12`, but would like to include current month too so it should start with `2023P1`

Comment: Do you just need to add -1 to your rownumber, so you add is 0 for the current month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP (14) Entity = 'Total_Group'
    , Scenario = 'Actual'
    , Date = TRIM(CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id) * -1 + 1, GETDATE())) as CHAR(4))
    + ' P'
    + CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id) * -1 + 1, GETDATE())) as VARCHAR(2)))
FROM [sys].[all_objects]
```

[image]